# how to save my QR generated image into gallery android?

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code

Here, I am generating Qr code as an image view. I want to save that image file into phone gallery. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all create bitmap from imageview using following code

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

now save this bitmap in internal storage

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
if (pictureFile == null) {
    Log.d(TAG,
            "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
    return;
} 
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
}  
}
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
 private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
// To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
// using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this. 
   File mediaStorageDir = new 
   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/Android/data/"
        + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
        + "/Files"); 

// This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
// between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

// Create the storage directory if it does not exist
if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        return null;
    }
} 
// Create a media file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
    String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);  
return mediaFile;
 }
```

Comment: here i am generating qr code..   bitmap = TextToImageEncode(EditTextValue);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);how can i convert imageview into bitmap?

Comment: ohh you not need to convert imageview to bitmap because you have already bitmap so call this method to store image in storage storeImage(bitmap);